# I'm getting a "usekeychain" error when attempting to clone my repository

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash, openssh

I'm currently receiving this error for trying to use git clone.

All the errors similar I have found have been for Mac and have some way of opening a configuration file, but from the description it seems like a Mac problem not a Windows one and I can't find the equivalent file on my device.

```
/c/Users/PC/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: usekeychain
/c/Users/PC/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: You can try to ignore it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74118685/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+ignore+usekeychain

Comment: First of all, try to test the SSH connection. `ssh -T <url>`
If needed add `-vv`
Check your `ssh/config`, it contains errors.

Answer (score 2):

The `UseKeychain` option is specific to Mac and you can't use it on Windows.  You should use a text editor to edit `/c/Users/PC/.ssh/config` (or, with a Windows text editor, `C:\Users\PC\.ssh\config`) and remove that line (which would be line 3).  The syntax you're getting for the file is for the Git Bash environment, which provides a limited Unix-like environment on Windows, and the path `/c/` is effectively `C:\`.

Once that's done, SSH should be functional again.

Comment: Alternatively, you can instruct ssh to ignore unknown options (as phd noted in a comment link).

Answer (score 0):

In the MacOS you can run this command to open the config file in the .ssh directory.

open ~/.ssh/config

In this file, you will see the below lines.

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

then,
remove the third line (UseKeychain yes)

It worked for me properly!